# Behaviour of capacitor right after switch is closed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

[image]

The flip S is closed,  find charge flown from P to Q

So I know at end behaviour of circuit, it should be just $ 15 uC$ just by applying kirchoff voltage law.  Initially before switch is flipped, the equivalent capacitance is $ \frac{6}{5}$

So, the charge on each capacitor is, $ 6 \mu C $ , Now for it to the change $15 \mu C $there must be a $9 \mu C$ difference. My friend told me that when the $2 \mu f$ capacitor is short circuit by closing of switch , at the instant the current starts flowing the system  as it is isolated and hence total charge in it must be conserved. Hence, the charge on 3uf capacitor is $ 12 uC$ and then  now it just need gain $3 \mu C$ to become $15 \mu C$.

My problem is I don't find last argument  for the charge conservation ( it is definitely not isolated due to the presence of the battery) where convincing and I am confused with taking sign of charges in  system after switch is open.

Comment: Most people don't know what abbreviations mean.  What is k.v.L.?  Also, state your units. 6/5 is just a number.

Comment: both capacitor systems preferably but for solving this particular question, I only need to know what happens to 3uf one. Pls convert your comment into answer I think it is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the concepts: 1) To get the equivalent capacitance, the individual capacitors must be added in series; 2) The total voltage drop across the equivalent capacitor is 5V before the switch is closed, allowing you to calculate the charge on the equivalent capacitor; 3) Because the capacitors are in series before the switch is closed, they each have the same charge on them, which is the charge calculated for the equivalent capacitor. This allows you to calculate voltage drop for each capacitor, which should add up to 5V. 4) The instant the switch is closed, the 3 micro-farad capacitor starts gaining charge from the battery because that capacitor is now getting charged to 5V. The 2 micro-farad capacitor is discharging because it is "shorted", as your friend told you.

Now, for the answer to your question:

1. From the concepts outlined above, calculate the charge on the 3 micro-farad capacitor
2. For a charging capacitor, the charge on it is found from a procedure that starts with Kirchhoff's loop rule, separates variables, and integrates the associated differential equation to arrive at

$Q=CV[1-e^{-t/(RC)}]$

Use this equation to calculate the time "t" at which the 3 micro-farad capacitor has the calculated charge, where "V" is equal to 5 volts

3. The current is calculated from $I=dQ/dt$, resulting in the equation

$I=V/R*e^{-t/(RC)}$, using the value of "t" obtained from the previous step

Regarding the value of "R", no resistance is shown in your circuit.  If you assume that R=0, you will obviously have a short circuit situation with a resultant infinite flow of current for a very short amount of time.  To obtain a result other than this trivial result, you need to know more information, such as the resistance of the wires running to the capacitor, the internal resistance of the battery, etc.

Comment: The final equation you wrote seems unusable in case where R=0 .. Am I suppose to take limit or something? How do I solve this question without that equation?

Comment: The case for R=0 is non-physical.  There will normally be resistance in the wires.  Even if you are using superconducting wires, there will be internal resistance in the battery.  You need more information, OR you must state that the capacitor instantly charges to 5 volts, which makes the current flow go infinite for an extremely short time interval (as I said, this is a non-physical situation).

Comment: ah it all makes sense now, thank you veyr much

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's description of the situation is a bit unclear, confusing and if I understand it correctly, incorrect. I'm not sure how charge conservation is helpful in this case (other than in the sense of Kirchhoff's current law), since the circuit can be seen as carrying no net charge. The charge in the $3\ \mu\textrm{F}$ doesn't acquire all of the charge of the $2\ \mu \text{F}$ because the switch is closed. A better way to describe what is happening to the $2\ \mu \text{F}$ capacitor is that since it is shorted upon closing the switch, the equal and opposite charge on its two plates neutralize.

I think you might be overthinking things. You know the initial and final charge on the $3\ \mu\text{F}$ capacitor. The answer you are looking for is the difference of the two: this charge has no way of flowing to the capacitor other than through the battery.

Perhaps you have a misconception about capacitors. The two capacitor plates carry equal and opposite charge, so a capacitor as a whole is actually electrically neutral. Whatever charge flows into one plate must also flow out the other.

Comment: I think the thing which I am struggling with is polarity of capacitor plates. Like what is sign of charge on each plate side. How exactly does one decide that?

Comment: Call the two capacitor plates $A$ and $B$. The charge on plate $A$ is $C(V_A - V_B)$, the charge on plate $B$ is $C(V_B - V_A)$, where $V$ denotes potential.